# Dynamic ejs layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ejs

I use a static site generator with markdown and ejs (also I have some vue some places).

I have these variables:
- post.name1
- post.name2
- post.name3
etc.

My ejs layout is following:

```
<%if(post.name1){%>
<div class="name"><%- post.name1 %>
</div>
<% } %>
<%if(post.name2){%>
<div class="name"><%- post.name2 %>
</div>
<% } %>
<%if(post.name3){%>
<div class="name"><%- post.name3 %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Instead of writing my code block three times (actually 59 times as I have 59 names), I want to write it just ONE (1) time like following for example and then it makes my layout as above:

```
<%if( name ){%>
<div class="name"><%- name %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Is it thus possible to make this possible so that my layout generates for all my 59 names by means of just this one code block (and some function)?

Comment: I'm curious why are you using ejs in the first place

Comment: @ZeRubeus - It came with the static site generator so I just "adopted" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% for(var i=1; i <= Object.keys(post).length ; i++) {%>
    <%if(post['name' + i]){%>
       <div class="name"><%- post['name' + i]%></div>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Try this, but you should definitely structure your post to be an array of objets so you can easily loop through it.